# Script to remote into multiple workstations

Tags: powershell

I currently have multiple training labs with 10-15 computers in each.  The problem is they all don't get used that often and after 60 days of inactivity, the computer gets blown from the domain and will need re-imaged.  Because of this, I remote into each desktop using mstsc and run gpupdate to keep everything up-to-date.

Is it possible to run a script that will remote into a group of workstations versus me running mstsc and entering each computer name in one at a time?  I'm new to scripts and wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I have a gpupdate script that was used before I started here and I have that on the startup for each computer.  I just need to remote in and log back off after its done.

From a programming standpoint I would say I need a array or vector of computer names and then have a loop read each line until it ends and an internal loop that will run the current pointer location name in mstsc.

Comment: Why not use a batch file ?

Comment: I guess I left this part out but when I'm saying logging in to each machine I also mean entering my pin for each MSTSC that I start.  I guess I was looking for a way to open each computer (like a list in a batch file) but then  include the password and log off after.  I want to be able to just log onto a separate admin machine, hit the script and it will open and auto log me in to get the gpupdate and then log off or restart after a certain time.

Comment: Is that pin a static value or is it generated each time ?

Comment: Is there a separate mechanism removing the computers from the domain after 60 days based on no user log-in?   If the computer were off or otherwise not contacting the domain through normal background processes - then yes, I'd see the machine account expiring.  But if they're on and connected to the domain, this sounds like an automated process unique to your environment that's causing the problem.  Or is this a matter of the *user* account's password expiring and causing problems?   
Either way, remotely automating an interactive UI log-in is unlikely to be your best approach (or easy to do.)

Comment: Yes, there is a monthly sweep of our accounts and if any computers are found to be inactive for 60+ days, they get blown from the domain. Currently, I need to log in once a month (to each computer) and update the group policy (also could get taken off of the domain if they are too far out of date on group policy).  My pin is just referring to me logging into the computer with my admin account and pass(pin). I'm logging into each with just my account and letting gpupdate run and then log off. I'm either in the labs walking through each workstation or I open remote sessions one after the other.

Comment: My recollection is that the machine policy will be continually (on an interval) refreshing in the background, assuming that hasn't been disabled.  GPUpdate is mainly, at that point, doing the user policy refresh.  Given the machine policy should be fine, if it were me, I'd look to exclude those machines from the sweep process rather than hacking together a way to keep them active with a user.  Depending on specifically what your sweep targets, you *might* get away with a PowerShell session as the user that loads the user profile.

Comment: To run gpupdate successfully from the PSSession, you may need to use an explicit credential, to enable the process to reach out to the DC.  This would interactively prompt: New-PSSession -ComputerName <name> -Credential $null

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@computers = @('Computer1','Computer2','Computer3')

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $computer -Force 
}
```

From: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/invoke-gpupdate?view=win10-ps

Make sure you have the "Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT)" feature installed, or you won't have the cmdlet available.

Ofcourse not sure how they check if a machine is inactive, but if they look at login, than this should do the trick.